# how to make any value positive(abs()) azure logic app?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have sales quantity as a in put which contains negative value also I have to parse it to all positive since there is no abs() function available in logic app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround to make it positive is to use sub() or mul() operations.

[image]

**output**

[image]

**Expression :**

`sub(0,variables('x'))`

`mul(-1,variables('x'))`

Comment: thank you  I used if command to solve it :)

Comment: if(greater(variables('sa'),0),variables('sa'),mul(variables('sa'),-1))